# Как убрать автоматический фокус TextBox при зпуске приложения

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, uwp

В разметке присутствует два элемента TextBox и один Button. Все это размещается в StackPanel. При запуске приложения в первом элементе TextBox мигает курсор. Скажите пожалуйста как запретить автоматический устанавливать фокус.

```
<StackPanel x:Name="stack_Box" Canvas.ZIndex="2" Grid.Row="1" >

<TextBox 
x:Name="textbox_Login" 
HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
Margin="0,20,0,0" Text="" 
VerticalAlignment="Top" 
Width="200" 
FontSize="20" 
GotFocus="textBox_Login_GotFocus" 
PlaceholderText="Логин"/>

<TextBox 
x:Name="textbox_Password" 
HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
Margin="0,20,0,0" 
TextWrapping="NoWrap" 
VerticalAlignment="Bottom" 
Width="200" 
FontSize="20" 
GotFocus="textBox_Password_GotFocus" 
PlaceholderText="Пароль"/>

<Button 
x:Name="button_Enter" 
Content="Войти" 
HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
Margin="0,20,0,0" 
VerticalAlignment="Bottom" 
Width="200" 
Canvas.ZIndex="2" 
FontSize="20" 
Foreground="White" />

</StackPanel>
```

Comment: В качестве быстрого хака, поставьте первым в таб-ордере невидимый фокусируемый элемент, и по приходу фокуса к нему отправьте этот самый фокус туда, куда вам надо.

Comment: Я не очень хорошо понял ваш метод.
У меня при фокусировке TextBox Логин или TextBox Пароль должна запускатся анимация. Когда я запускаю приложение анимация запускается т.к. фокус уже стоит.

Comment: Ну, смысл в том, чтобы при старте фокус достался вашему невидимому элементу, а не анимированному тексбоксу.

Comment: До меня дошло, то, что Вы имели ввиду. Быстрый хак получился. Спасибо.

Comment: Окей, тогда оформлю как ответ.

Answer (score 2):

(Вынесено из комментариев)

В качестве быстрого хака, поставьте первым в таб-ордере невидимый фокусируемый элемент. Тогда при старте приложения этот невидимый элемент получит фокус вместо текстбокса. Вы можете по приходу фокуса либо переправить его куда вам нужно, либо оставить на этом элементе.

Если вам важен в программе tab order, имеет смысл убрать этот невидимый элемент, как только фокус с него уйдёт. Он выполнил свою роль, и не должен мешать.